# DOSKEY doesn't work in succession

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

If I define a command as such:

```
DOSKEY say=echo $*
```

And then run it like this:

```
say hello&&say goodbye
```

The output is:

```
hello
'say' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I expect it to print `hello` and `goodbye` on two lines.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a little bit of testing, what seems to be happening is that all of `hello&&say goodbye` is being passed to your first `say` macro (and essentially anything else in that same line). Unfortunately, you can't call macros from inside other macros.

To demonstrate, I changed your macro a bit:

```dos
C:\>doskey say=echo "$*"

C:\>doskey /macros
say=echo "$*"

C:\>say hello&&say goodbye
"hello&&say goodbye"
```

So far, I've not found a way around this.

Comment: Then this should have been a comment, not an answer

Comment: It answers the question of “what gives?”.